# Zebra ZPL code Repeat label X times

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

Using a Zebra printer with ZPL code that encodes a specific label, how can I add a to the existing ZPL command so it prints 3 copies of the same label.

This would have to be part of the ZPL code as sending the command 3 times is not an option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have no serial numbers you can add ^PQ3 to your ZPL stream.

From the ZPL Manual

^PQ – Print Quantity
The ^PQ command gives control over several printing operations. It controls the number of labels to print, the number of labels printed before printer pauses, and the number of replications of each serial number.

**Format: ^PQq,p,r,o,e**
If the o parameter is set to Y, the printer cuts but does not pause, and the printer does not pause after every group count of labels has been printed. With the o parameter set to N (default), the printer pauses after every group count of labels has been printed.

**Parameters Details**
q = total quantity of labels to print
Values: 1 to 99,999,999
Default: 1

p = pause and cut value (labels between pauses)
Values: 1 to 99,999,999
Default: 0 (no pause)

r = replicates of each serial number
Values: 0 to 99,999,999 replicates
Default: : 0 (no replicates)

o = override pause count
Values:
N = no
Y = yes
Default: N

e = cut on error label (RFID void is an error label)
Values:
N = no - if a cutter is installed, a cut will be made after a voided RIFD label
ONLY if a cut would be made after the non-voided label and this was the last
retry.
Y = yes - if a cutter is installed, a cut will be made after ANY voided RFID label.
Default: Y

Example: This example shows the control over print operations:
^PQ50,10,1,Y: This example prints a total of 50 labels with one replicate of each serial number. It
prints the total quantity in groups of 10, but does not pause after every group.

^PQ50,10,1,N: This example prints a total of 50 labels with one replicate of each serial number. It
prints the total quantity in groups of 10, pausing after every group.

Answer (score 1):

at the end of your command before ^XZ add ^PQ3. this will print the label 3 times.

^PQ3^XZ                             ////  ^PQ3 will print 3 times
^PQ10^XZ                         /// ^PQ10 times