# Printing on two labels at the same time with ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have a roll of labels that are 5,1cm x 1,6cm (two per row) and I need to print two different labels on each row ([expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNaXw.png)), but the print command of the ZPL format only prints one label and feeds the next, leaving the adjacent label blank.

This is the ZPL code that I have:

```
^XA
~TA000
~JSN
^LT0
^MNW
^MTT
^PON
^PMN
^LH0,0
^JMA
^PR8,8
~SD15
^JUS
^LRN
^CI27
^PA0,1,1,0
^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW871
^LL152
^LS0
^BY2,3,60^FT23,73^B3N,N,,N,N
^FDId_bono^FS
^FT90,120^A0N,47,46^FB220,1,12,C^FH\^CI28^FDId_bono^FS^CI27
^PQ1,,,Y
^XZ
```

I believe that I need to add in this label a shift to print side by side label-1 and label-2 and print two at I time, but I cannot figure out how to add a side-shift in the label.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zebra ZPL code Repeat label X times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621272/zebra-zpl-code-repeat-label-x-times)

Comment: @MartinZeitler, sorry, no, I need two different labels on each "row", not the same label twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to print both labels as a single format, using `^LH` to shift the second label to the right the appropriate number of dots.  Basically, something like:

```
^XA
^LH0,0
... left label here ...
^LHnnn,0
... right label here ...
^LH0,0
^XZ
```

The first and third `^LH` commands reset the home position.  The second `^LH` shifts it to the right `nnn` dots.

Comment: Cool trick with the label home! nicely done

Comment: How do I figure out the NNN dots?

Comment: The NNN is based on how far right you want the label to appear, and the DPI of your printer.  For example, if you want it moved 31mm right at 8dpmm (203dpi), then NNN would be 8 * 31 = 248.